# RGBDSLAM -- points of interest

Tags: ros, slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to get all of the points of interest detected with rgbdslam including depth.

So what are the topics to use with RGBDSLAM to get all of the points of interest (SIFT) detected during the creation of the 3D map ?

I think all of these topics will help me:
/rgbdslam/online_clouds          /rgbdslam/pose_graph_markers

but I'm not sure what are published in these topics. Are they SIFT points (and where is the origin of x, y and z in this case ?).
Thanks for reply

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223811/rgbdslam----points-of-interest/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rgbdslam doesn't send the features. The topic you mention is for visualization of the poses only.

I've recently wrote a addition to send ORB features on a custom topic, but haven't published it, because I thought there wouldn't be any demand. If you have some ROS and C++ skill, I can create a branch for you that should be easily adapted to SIFT.

[Update:]

Checkout the new branch [*feature-msg-output*](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/tree/feature-msg-output) on github. It works for sending out ORB features on the topic */rgbdslam/features*.
The message *msg/Feature.msg* defines a `uint8[] descriptor`. For SIFT (or SURF) you probably want to change that to `float32[] descriptor`

In node.cpp, method `Node::toFeatureMessage()` you need to reflect that change, by replacing `unsigned char` with `float`. And replace the `CV_8UC1` in the if-condition by `CV_32FC1`.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on 2016-01-15**:
Hello Felix,
Thanks for reply.

Yes I have ROS and C++ skills. Tell me where to get this new branch, I will test it and give you feedbacks.

Thanks again !